# To attend a school, to take a class

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Comment peut-on traduire ces phrases en Français?

1. I **attended** the University of Michigan from 1997 to 2001.
2. I **took** a French class at Alliance Française last month.

Je devine :

1. Je **fréquentais** l'Université de Michigan de 1997 à 2001.
2. J'ai **pris** une classe de français a l'Alliance Française le mois dernier.

Est-ce juste ? Peut-on utiliser d'autres mots ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pour le 2., je dirais *un cours* plutôt que *une classe*. Tu peux aussi remplacer *pris* par *suivi*, mais les deux sont justes.

Pour le 1. *fréquenter* est le bon verbe, tu aurais aussi pu utiliser *étudier*. Sinon, si tu veux changer la phrase, tu pourrais aussi dire

> J'étais élève/étudiant à l'université du Michigan…

Comment: Je pense que le mot "élève" ou "étudiant" est de trop. `J'ai été à l'université du Michigan...` est largement suffisant.

Comment: J'ai *pris* est beaucoup moins formel, et il me semble que ça désigne plus le fait de s'inscrire au cours que d'y avoir un quelquonque résultat. Par exemple « j'ai pris ce cours, mais je n'y suis jamais allé ».

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Je ne dirais pas ça, mais c'est vrai que c'est assez informel. Mais *suivi* n'est pas si formel que ça.

Comment: @BatchyX Je ne suis pas d'accord : « étudiant à l'université ... » est exactement l'expression qui convient. Et je dirais bien « suivi un cours », « prendre un cours » se comprend mais n'est pas du tout idiomatique.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Le pluriel passe mieux ("*prendre **des** cours*").

Answer (score -1):

1. Cf. ce que dit Evpok.
2. Le verbe "*participer*" peut aussi convenir :

> J'ai participé à un cours de Français à l'Alliance Française le mois
>   dernier.

Après il y a aussi la conjugaison du verbe à prendre en compte. Si le contexte d'utilisation de ces phrases nécessite un langage soutenu (courrier administratif, lettre de motivation...), utilise l'imparfait au détriment du passé simple. Si au contraire le contexte est moins formel et si le langage courant peut être acceptable, alors tu peux uiliser le passé composé.

Comment: Toute mon incompétence en la matière soutient le passé composé.

Comment: Je ne dirais pas *participer* pour avoir suivi un cours. Pour moi, ça voudrait plutôt dire avoir été l'un des enseignants de ce cours. *Participer*, c'est actif.

Comment: @Gilles: C'est sûr que dans un CV c'est ambigu. J'aurais plutôt tendance à l'utiliser pour une participation occasionnelle, et indistinctement en tant qu'intervenant ou simple spectateur.

Comment: Seul le passé composé (action terminée et intention d'indiquer qu'elle est révolue au moment présent) est possible ici.  On ne « soutient » pas un langage en le déformant de façon inappropriée.

Answer (score -1):

1. Je fréquentais l'Université de Michigan de 1997 à 2001.
2. J'ai pris une classe de français à l'Alliance Française le mois dernier.

ou :

1. J'ai étudié à l'Université du Michigan de 1997 à 2001.
2. J'ai participé à une formation en français dans l'établissement *Alliance Française* le mois dernier.