# How do you say "attend" in French?

Tags: anglais, vocabulaire

What word in French would you use for *attend*, in the sense "attend the class"? *Attendre* seems to mean *to wait*; dictionary offers:

> visiter
>   fréquenter
>   hanter
>   s'approcher

but I guess only some of them are normally used in this context?

Comment: Related, but *different*: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/to-attend-a-school-to-take-a-class

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would have used none of them. To be exact, my usual translation of “to attend a class” is “*assister à un cours*”.

Comment: strange... in the dictionary, I find that assister means to help or support. But true, google translate [offers the same](http://translate.google.com/#auto/fr/attend). Thanks!

Comment: @Tomas You're right, to help/support is the first meaning of the word. I can only suggest [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/assister) as a better reference though.

Comment: @Tomas _Assister_ has different meanings.

Comment: @Tomas, "assister à qqch" means attend something or be present when something occurs, "assister qqun" mean help or support someone.

Answer (score 12):

You could also use the word *suivre*.

> Twice a week she attends French classes. *Deux fois par semaines elle **suit** des cours de français.*

Comment: thanks, yes, this is also the [second option google translate has offered](http://translate.google.com/#auto/fr/attend) (after *assister*)!

Answer (score 4):

In the context of an active attendance, *participer* is suitable.

> I will attend this meeting. *Je participerai à cette réunion.*

Comment: As for the future tense, I've heard it is not used much in spoken word. So isn't it more common to say *Je vais participer à cette réunion*?

Comment: I see you live in Paris, are you a native speaker? Sorry for this question, but there's no other way of getting the information. I think for the purpose of this site [the native language information of a user should be available the profile.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3966/13045)

Comment: "Je participerai" is a (little) bit more formal than "je vais participer" but you can use it when speaking. I do, actually :)

Comment: I'm just discovering your second comment. Yes, I am french. "Français 2nde langue", in my profile, is just a joke. And you are absolutely right, the native language information is more than useful. The location too.

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on the 3 "correct" answers, there are some differences in the 3 proposed translations

- *assister à un cours* : you are going to attend the class at a specific date. It not mean that you are attending the class for a whole semester.
- *suivre un cours* : here you are attending the class which lasts for several sessions
- *participer à un cours* / *prendre part à un cours* : as @Shlublu noted, active attendance is implied. Nothing implied about the number of sessions.

Comment: Then you make it a fourth good answer.... +1 to all!