# "faire un cours" for "take a class"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

"I took a French class last year."

In this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/to-attend-a-school-to-take-a-class) it is claimed that "suivre un cours" is the best option, with "prendre un cours" also usable but not idiomatic. What about "faire un cours"? Is it also a valid option?

> J'ai fait un cours de français l'année dernière.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "j'ai fait un cours" we can understand that you were the teacher. 
I think "suivre" is the best option.

You can say : "j'ai eu des cours de français l’année dernière"

Or : "J'ai assisté à des cours de français l'année dernière"

But "J'ai suivi des cours de français" is better because it seems that you were more involve.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the most idiomatic translation is "J'ai suivi un cours de français l'année dernière".

"Suivre des cours" (note the plural) can be used both for a one or two hour class lesson or for a semester long class (shorter or longer period of time as well)

Note that "prendre un cours" has the meaning "to take notes on a copybook".

I might as well add "Reprendre un cours" is used when you were absent from a class or you didn't have time to take all notes, so you borrow your classmate's notebook to copy out.